# Is my one time pad cipher secure?

Tags: one-time-pad

This is a program that I made for encrypting text files. It uses a one time pad cipher to encrypt the files, but I do not know if there is any holes in my program that could be a vulnerability. Is my one time pad cipher secure?

```
import os
q = 1
while q == 1:
    e = raw_input("file to encypt: ")
    #This will open a file for encryption
    o = open(e, "r")
    o1 = o.read()
    #This is the plain text to encrypt
    #'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
    plain = o1
    #This will measure the length of the plain text
    f3 = len(plain)
    #generate random chacters as long as the text
    a1 = os.urandom(f3)
    #makes the random characters tuple format
    b = list(a1)
    b2 = list(plain)
    s = plain
    #gives the ascii value of the charters
    L = [ord(c) for c in s]
    s = a1
    a = [ord(c) for c in s]
    b = [ord(c) for c in plain]
    #adds the random digits and the plain text
    c = map(sum, zip(a,b))
    #uses Modular arithmetic if the sum is greater than 256
    x=c
    z = []
    for y in x:
        z.append(y-256 if y>=256 else y)
    z = [y-256 if y >= 256 else y for y in x]
    #converts the sum back to charter form
    cipher_text = ''.join(chr(i) for i in z)
    #makes a folder for the files
    base1 = os.path.basename(e)
    base2 = os.path.splitext(base1)[0]
    #makes a folder for the output
    p = "/Users/kyle/one_time_pad/"+base2
    print p
    if os.path.exists(p):
        print
    else:
        os.mkdir(p)

    key = a1
    #makes a file containg the key
    p = p + "/"
    f2 = p+"key.txt"
    #print f2
    if os.path.exists(f2):
        f1 = file(f2, "w")
        f1 = open(f2, "w")
        f1.write(key)
        f1.close()
    else:
        f1 = file(f2, "w")
        f1 = open(f2, "w")
        f1.write(key)
        f1.close()

    #makes a file containg the cipher text
    f3 = p+"cipher_text.txt"
    if os.path.exists(f3):
        f1 = file(f3, "w")
        f1 = open(f3, "w")
        f1.write(cipher_text)
        f1.close()
    else:
        f1 = file(f3, "w")
        f1 = open(f3, "w")
        f1.write(cipher_text)
        f1.close()

    f4 = p+"encrypt.py"
    encrypt1 = open("/Users/kyle/encrypt.py", "r")
    encrypt = encrypt1.read()
    if os.path.exists(f4):
        f1 = file(f4, "w")
        f1 = open(f4, "w")
        f1.write(encrypt)
        f1.close()
    else:
        f1 = file(f4, "w")
        f1 = open(f4, "w")
        f1.write(encrypt)
        f1.close()

    f5 = p+"decrypt.py"
    encrypt1 = open("/Users/kyle/decrypt.py", "r")
    encrypt = encrypt1.read()
    if os.path.exists(f5):
        f1 = file(f5, "w")
        f1 = open(f5, "w")
        f1.write(encrypt)
        f1.close()
    else:
        f1 = file(f5, "w")
        f1 = open(f5, "w")
        f1.write(encrypt)
        f1.close()

    print 50*"-"
```

This is the code that i use for decryption

```
import os

q = 1
while q == 1: 
    #opens the cipher text and it converts it to decimal
    cipher = raw_input("cipher text: ")
    cipher1 = open(cipher, "r")
    cipher2 = cipher1.read()
    cipher3 = [ord(c) for c in cipher2]

    #opens the key and coverts it to decimal
    key = raw_input("key: ")
    key1 = open(key, "r")
    key2 = key1.read()
    key3 = [ord(c) for c in key2]

    #subtracts the key from the cipher
    a = cipher3
    b = key3
    c = map(lambda x: (x[0]-x[1]) % 256, zip(a,b))

    #prints out the decrypted plain text
    decrypt = ''.join(map(chr,c))
    #makes a file with the decrypted output 
    path1 = raw_input("out folder: ")
    name = "plain_text.txt"
    path2 = path1 + "/" + name
    if os.path.exists(path2):
        f1 = file(path2, "a")
        f1 = open(path2, "a")
        f1.write(decrypt)
        f1.close()
    else:
        f1 = file(path2, "w")
        f1 = open(path2, "w")
        f1.write(decrypt)
        f1.close()

    print 50*"-"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first hole I see is that you're using the random generator `urandom`. How do you know that the sequence generated by this function is truly random?

The second hole is that you're saving the key as plaintext!

Answer (score -1):

You should not use `os.urandom`, as the module is a PRNG based on a seed number.
Instead, you should use `/dev/random`.

Saving the key as plaintext is not a bad idea. It's a HORRIBLE IDEA.
If you are coding python on Linux, save the key in a `WAVE Audio File`.
And if you are coding Py' on Windows, save it as `Executable`
Both are a horrible idea of stenography, but it's the basic.
And as saving it on these file formats, use DeepSound.
And well, save the key on a hard drive is not recommended. Save it on a USB Flash Drive, Micro SD Card, or, whatever.
Yet make sure the medium containing the key-file it's fully encrypted, i recommend you creating your own AES Hard Drive encryption aplication, or just compiling VeraCrypt from source.
The AES key should be delivered in plaintext, in paper, NOT A DIGITAL MEDIUM, and should be delivered face to face for the message receiver.
When decrypting, the machine shoul'd be FULLY OFFLINE, and far from smartphones, or anything that have a internet connection (WIFI, or Mobile Data), for preventing BitWhisper or Acoustic cryptanalysis.

Sorry if i look like a paranoid, but i am one! ;-)

Source about PRNG, Acoustic cryptanalysis: Wikipedia.
Source about `/dev/random`: https://cryptoanarchy.freed0m4all.net/wiki/One_Time_Pad